# Espresso Testing check if string value of TextView in Listview does not exist

Tags: android, android-espresso, matcher

I have a ListView that contains an ArrayList. Food.class contains String values like eg FoodName. Now I want to check if after deletion of a row from the ListView the Value FoodName does not exist at the specific position anymore. I tried following code which does not work:

```
onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list))
            .atPosition(0)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.food_name))
            .check("I don't know how to check if string value of food_name which I deleted before does not exist here anymore")
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list))
            .atPosition(0)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.food_name))
            .check(matches(not(withText("Your old text"))));
```

or

```
onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list))
            .atPosition(0)
            .check(matches(not(hasDescendant(withText("Your old text")))));
```

PS. I look to the [expresso cheatsheet](https://developer.android.com/images/training/testing/espresso-cheatsheet.png) and is very useful when I face this kind of questions.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just missed that not() matcher... Yep I already used this cheatsheet but the not() matcher is a method of org.hamcrest.Matchers. That was the missing part and the exact positioning of this matcher. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: You are right, you have to know also the hamcrest matchers sometimes, some of them are also specified in the cheatsheet as "Object Matchers"

Comment: Personally, I like to use [Barista](https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista) to simplyfy the test writting

Comment: seems to be pretty handy and easy to write but I think I will stick to the normal espresso testing to learn all the features and functions of espresso testing first and in other project the change to Barista will be more convinient and I will more or less know what it will do in background